# Find shortest path in maze with landmines and limited lives

Tags: algorithm, shortest-path, maze

I've encountered a problem I'm having a bit of trouble solving. I am trying to write a program that solves an m by n grid maze that has landmines in it. The tricky part is that the player/maze runner has a L >= 1 number of lives, meaning they can step on a maximum of L - 1 landmines before they will die on the next landmine.

Further details:

-Each cell can be connected to any of the adjacent cells. All connections are two-way.

-We can assume that the maze has a correct path from start to end given the number of lives.

-The maze can contain loops or 'islands' where two paths from a given cell lead to the same cell.

My current thoughts:

I have tried a variety of approaches to this problem. There is the obvious brute force solution which involves traversing every possible path and taking the one with the lowest distance. But that is exponential time. I feel that there may be a Dijkstra-like or A*-like solution that leads to O(n + vlogv) time. Vanilla Dijkstra or A* do not lead to solutions for this problem since the state of the graph effectively changes depending on how it is traversed. I have also tried a variety of breadth first search + tracing back to start using priority queue. These schemes, after further investigation, can lead to exponential time.

The most promising idea I've come up with so far involves parsing each maze into a graph and performing a modified Dijkstra. Each cell with three or more connections will be a node. Each cell with two connections is part of a path. Each cell with one connection can be discarded. The end result is a graph. You then perform something similar to Dijkstra, but I have not yet clarified a solution.

I can only guess that this solution requires an algorithm that is efficient in the best case but can become exponential in the worst case.

Comment: one alternative that i can think of is doing modified dijkstra, where the distance is dist[node][Lives_left] and you start from dist[source][L] = 0.

complexity should be O(|E| + VL log VL)

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely go for Dynamic Programming(DP) style of algorithms.

If you would have added an example maze matrix here then it would have made easy for me to understand the problem.

You problem is quite similar to [this](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-shortest-safe-route-in-a-path-with-landmines/). So have a read at it. But before going directly to the solution read [this tutorial](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/notes/dynamic-programming-problems-involving-grids/).

Answer (score 0):

The state during a maze traverse consists of the cell and the number of lives left, so you can represent the set of possible traverses as a graph with `N*L` vertices (where N is the number of cells.)

To simplify slightly, you can fold all L final vertices in into a single final vertex, since the number of remaining lives at the end of the traverse is irrelevant.

You can then use any shortest-paths algorithm to find a solution.

The transformed graph has approximately L times as many vertices and L times as many edges, so it will multiply the complexity by L².

Comment: In the process of generating this graph, wouldn't you solve the problem before you got to the step where you employ a shortest path algorithm?

Comment: @aimesce: you can generate the graph without any knowledge of the solution. A transition from a cell with lives remaining `lv` to its neighbour either has lives remaining `lv-1` or `lv`, depending only on whether the neighbour has a landmine. In practice, you would construct the graph on demand as you arrive at a cell during the BFS.

Comment: I think I understand this solution, but I'm having trouble understanding the time complexity. Firstly, what is L in this instance? Is it the total number of possible paths?

Comment: L is your L: the maximum number of landmines in a viable path. But I think I overestated the complexity. If you do it right, it will be linear in L, not quadratic. Do you have a sample maze?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the maze to be a graph with a node for every clear square, and an edge between each pair of connected squares.

Let N be the number of nodes in the graph.  Assign each edge a cost of N*k+1, where k is the number of land mines it touches (either 0, 1, or 2).  This ensures that moving over a landmine will cost 2N more than moving over a clear square.

Now use Dijkstra's algorithm to find the shortest path through the graph.

Comment: I'm not sure this would work. Movement over a landmine should be zero if the player has more than one life left.

Comment: It works.  This finds the path that costs the fewest lives.  If there's more than one that costs the fewest lives, then it uses the number of steps to break ties.  There's no need to keep track of how many lives you have left.

Comment: I think I miscommunicated something. That or I'm not quite understanding this solution. I failed to mention that every square that has a mine in it may only have a single mine in it.

Is there any way to illustrate some scenarios here in StackOverflow? I'm not yet familiar with the formatting.

Comment: I figured that.  For the possible paths to be ordered properly, I just needed the cost of walking over a mine to be greater than the costs of all mine-free steps together.  I count the same cost on entry and exit so we don't have to keep track of which direction an edge is followed.

Comment: @matt: but that algorithm favours lives over length, no? If there is a long landmine-free path and a landmine-infested shortcut, the shortcut won't be selected even if it is viable. (But the double counting of landmines is clever.)

Comment: @rici, yes indeed.  The question didn't specify a preference, but I like to finish mazes with as many lives as possible.  If you want the shortest viable path then a solution like yours is appropriate.

Comment: @Matt, Ah, it looks like this is where I miscommunicated. The ending life count is irrelevant as long as the player still has at least one life left. The problem is just to find the shortest path without dying, with a hard requirement on finding the shortest path.

But thanks for your input. The solution for the problem you solved is quite clever.